# Set programmatically dialog's title dimensions

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

Is it possible to adjust a Dialog's title dimensions like this?

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.setTitle("Title");
    dialog.setTitleWidth(X); // Clearly doesn't exist
    dialog.setTitleHeight(Y); // Clearly doesn't exist
    return dialog;
}
```

Or must be done through XML? Or is it impossible to control the title's dimensions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Dialog with a custom layout.
[This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) can help you.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that page, but the question is if I can modify the preexisting title.